# Return multiple strings from dll

Tags: c++, string, windows, dll

we are having a discussion as what is a good way to return multiple strings from one dll function. Currently we have 8 strings, but there will be more. For simplicity I now consider all strings will have equal lengths.

```
extern "C" int DLLNAME_ _stdcall GetResult(TestResults* testResults);
```

where

```
struct TestResults
{
    int stringLengths;
    char* string1;
    char* string2;
    char* string3;
    char* string4;
    ...
};
```

or second option: where

```
struct TestResults
{
    int stringLengths;
    char string1[64];
    char string2[64];
    char string3[64];
    char string4[64];
    ...
};
```

third option:
extern "C" int DLLNAME_ _stdcall GetResult(int stringLengths, char* string1, char* string2, char* string3, ...);

The dll will communicate over a serial line and retrieve information that will be filled into the strings. Where the memory needs to be allocated is open for discussion and can be part of the answer.

The background is that we have a VB6 application team that prefers the second method and a C++/C# team that prefers the first method. Last method looks to suit both teams but looks a bit strange to me with so many parameters.

Maybe there are more options. What is common practice under Windows? Any examples from the Windows API or arguments to choose one over the other?

Edit: The strings have a meaning as in first name, last name, email. We currently have eight, but in the future we might add a couple for example for address. An array would not be the correct choice for this, but that was not clear from the original context.

Comment: With `char*` how is the memory allocation/deallocation managed?  Also concider `BSTR` as an inter-language type (with defined memory management).

Comment: I updated the question to answer your comment. We have no strict rule to say where the allocation needs to happen. This is probably part of the reason why we end up not knowing what would be a good / common idea.

Comment: If you're interoperating with VB 6, you *absolutely* should use `BSTR`. That's what VB 6 uses as its string type. Works fine from .NET applications, too, since it's a standard COM type.

Comment: or you can return it in form [`REG_MULTI_SZ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884(v=vs.85).aspx) - *A sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string (\0).

The following is an example:

String1\0String2\0String3\0LastString\0\0*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is probably using a **safe array** storing `BSTR` strings.

Both VB and C# understand safe arrays very well: in C#, a safe array of `BSTR` strings is *automatically* converted to a `string[]` array.

On the C++ side, you can use the `ATL::CComSafeArray` helper class to simplify safe array programming.

You will find interesting material in [this MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795188.aspx) (in particular, take a look at the paragraph *Producing a Safe Array of Strings*).

---

From the aforementioned article: On the C++ side, you can implement a *C-interface* DLL, exporting a function like this:

```
extern "C" HRESULT MyDllGetStrings(/* [out] */ SAFEARRAY** ppsa)
{
  try {  
    // Create a SAFEARRAY containing 'count' BSTR strings
    CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa(count);

    for (LONG i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      // Use ATL::CComBSTR to safely wrap BSTR strings in C++
      CComBSTR bstr = /* your string, may build from std::wstring or CString */ ;

      // Move the the BSTR string into the safe array
      HRESULT hr = sa.SetAt(i, bstr.Detach(), FALSE);

      if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Error...
        return hr;
      }
    }

    // Return ("move") the safe array to the caller
    // as an output parameter (SAFEARRAY **ppsa)
    *ppsa = sa.Detach();

  } catch (const CAtlException& e) {
    // Convert ATL exceptions to HRESULTs
    return e;
  }

  // All right
  return S_OK;
}
```

On the C# side, you can use this PInvoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void MyDllGetStrings(
  [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
  out string[] result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you declare your function as `extern "C"` I suppose that you cannot use `std::vector<std::string>` as return type.

Another possibility would be:

```
struct String
{
   int         size; /* size of string */
   const char* str;  /* actual string  */
}
struct TestResults
{
   int     size; /* number of strings             */
   String* arr;  /* pointer to an array of String */
};
```

and then the same as before:

```
extern "C" int DLLNAME_ _stdcall GetResult(TestResults* testResults);
```

With that you are flexible to return as much strings as you like. Also loop through your `TestResults` is easy.

**Edit #1:** As said in the comments: use **[BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx)**. So your struct would look like:

```
struct TestResults
{
   int   size; /* number of strings           */
   BSTR* arr;  /* pointer to an array of BSTR */
};
```

A `BSTR` will be [allocated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xda6xzx7.aspx) by: `BSTR MyBstr = SysAllocString(L"I am a happy BSTR");`. This allocation also sets the member which contain the length of the string. You have to free the allocated memory with: `SysFreeString(MyBstr);`. Also you need to allocate the whole array `BSTR*`.

Comment: Compare your `String` type to the MS-Windows type `BSTR` (note that BSTR has defined inter-language memory management)

Comment: You should not use the STL types as return values in DLLs anyway. They cannot be used interchangeably across different versions of the runtime libraries.

Comment: I strongly recommend offering a separate freeResult function anyway. This makes deallocation easy for the user, no matter how many different arrays need to be deallocated. With that, there is no need for BSTR any more either, we could get back to simple C strings again. We even could return the struct as a pointer (NULL on error)... These two functions would then be the equivalent to the Sys(Alloc|Free)String pair...

Comment: ... and there is no need to worry about *how* strings were allocated, we could even use operators new[] and delete[].

Comment: That would work fine, @Aconcagua, and is the recommended pattern when you want to use anything that requires memory management, including the STL types. It is also a truly "universal" API, since it works with all languages, from assembly and C, to Python and Haskell. Unfortunately, it puts a more burden on the programmer, which is a particular disadvantage in languages that don't normally require manual memory management, where programmers aren't disciplined. BSTR has the advantage of being a COM type, ubiquitous in Windows, and automatically managed in VB & .NET. Convenient, and less errors.

Comment: @CodyGray That does not really fit together to what I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7.aspx)... This is C/C++, though, so I imagine the freeResult function is still a need for these languages... Sure, I'm not experienced with VB6 at all, though, possibly it applies automatically memory management to COM objects... If so, however, the problem of the BSTR array remains - isn't there then some COM array type, too?

Comment: @CodyGray Hm, seems to me as if Mr.C64 provided the appropriate answer...

Comment: Yes, VB 6 and VB.NET are very different languages from C and C++. Yes, there is a COM array type: SafeArray. And yes, I like Mr.C64's answer. :-) @Aconcagua

Comment: Me too, nice answer. Doesn't know SafeArray before.